# removeAttribute Error in setExtremes with new version 1.3.3 in IE8

Tags: highcharts

I used highstock.js 1.3.1 and everything was fine. Now I changed to 1.3.3 and in IE8 and IE7 I get an error when using setExtremes:

Object doesn't support property or method "removeAttribute".

My chart has to work with these old IE-versions, should I stay at 1.3.1 or is there a solution?

Comment: Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle? This may be new bug in Highcharts. Meanwhile I advice to use 1.3.1

Comment: Solved - I have to use a newer JQuery version, too.